# How to fix Pandas Import AttributeError "type object 'numpy.ndarray' has no attribute '__array_function__' "

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm unable to import pandas. I'm using python3.6.7 and pandas version 0.23.4 
Whenever i do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
```

I get the following ErrorMessage:

[image]

I've tried the following but none of these seem to work:

1. Restart Jupyter Notebook
2. Uninstall pandas(0.23.4) and reinstall it
3. Uninstall pandas(0.23.4) and install pandas(0.22)

Came across these on google but they don't work.
What else should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from numpy-v1.16.0 that has been released today. Try to uninstall v1.16.0 and install an earlier version.

`pip3 uninstall numpy`

`pip3 install numpy==1.15.0`

EDIT:

You will now be getting the following warning.

`/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py:222: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  return f(*args, **kwds)`

which you can filter out with the following:

`import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message="numpy.dtype size changed")`

But for me, the best way to solve the issue was to run `pip3 uninstall numpy` and then manually delete all numpy directories from.
`/home/USER/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/` because for whatever reason `pip` doesn't uninstall all of the packages.

and then just run `pip3 install numpy`. Now you have the current version of numpy with no errors or warnings.

Comment: Thank you so much @michael0196 . The issue was with the numpy version as you suggested. Works now.